# WAMP: How to "Install Database Schema by Running Command ..."

Tags: database, schema, wamp

At a higher-ed institution and I am trying to install an app called "Guide on the Side" (https://github.com/ualibraries/Guide-on-the-Side). It sits on a LAMP stack of varying flavors, but--of course--we are a Windows-based institution. My question is of the "what does that mean!?" variety.

I have my db created, the config "configurated," but then there's the following procedure:

> Install the database schema by running the following commands from the guide_on_the_side/app folder:
>   ../lib/Cake/Console/cake Migrations.migration --plugin Tags all
>   ../lib/Cake/Console/cake Migrations.migration all

Can someone translate? Can I actually "run" this in a windows cmd. I've some familiarity with terminals in *Nix OS's but I neeeeever touch the command line on Windows, so I'm just out of my element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cake` is a console command (shell script) for the CakePHP application framework.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html

You should be able to run the `cake` command from the Windows shell (it will refer to the `cake.bat` batch file).

You may need to make other adjustments for [running CakePHP apps on IIS](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/cakephp-on-iis).

Comment: That wasn't initially clear to me, being unfamiliar with CakePHP - but once it dawned on me I found this part anyway pretty painless to walk through. For posterity, I had trouble at first with cmd not recognizing php as "an internal or external command," but Once I added php and the cake console to my environment variables I was kind of relieved to see everything working like it should. Thanks for the pointers.